# Add custom Shortcut in NavBarControl

Tags: c#, devexpress

I would like to give the user to add his own shortcut in the `navBarControl`
let me explain.

I have a `navBarControl` with two `NavBarGroup` ( element and shortcut)
I'd like to give the user the ability to add his own shortcut in the `NavBarGroup`(shortcut).

For example: he like to add a shortcut for `saveButton`, he goes on the `saveButton` left click, add shortcut
and when I reopen the app, I get all my shortcut added

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, **NavBarControl** does not provide the ShortCut
>   functionality.

Here is a DevExpress QA thread - [Navbr Shortcuts](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q398674), which suggest to implement shortcut functionality on the Form Level.

Reference:
[Nav Bar shortcut](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CQ42966)
[Assigning shortcut keys (accelerators) to navigation bar item's caption at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q462126)